# Swift - UIScrollView Scrolls Partially

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, autolayout

My problem is slightly different from other's 'Swift UIScrollView' problems when using auto layout:

Problem:
Unlike others, when I run my app, it scrolls. My problem is that the scroll cuts off the bottom 20-30% of the content. I can pull to see the buttons did build and are down there, but when I let it go the scroll snaps back to a false bottom which cuts off my content!!! I've been trying, for days, to fix it to scroll the entire height but it continues to cut off!!

Description of app:
I used auto layout to layout 6 buttons and labels. Each button a rectangular image, with a label directly beneath it. (sorry, the site won't let me post pictures!)

I have my views arranged like this: 
MainView > ScrollView > ContentView > Buttons & Labels

I have my contentView pinned to my ScrollView and my ScrollView pinned to my MainView. My buttons and labels all have constraints that are building correctly, to create a list that looks like:

Rectangular button
Label beneath it
Spacing
Rectangular button
Label beneath it
Spacing
Etc.

Can anyone tell me why I can't scroll the full length of the view?

Comment: I know working with scrollviews are a pain. Most of the time to get them to work properly you will have to programmatically adjust constraints. Also, have you looked into setting/adjusting the `UIScrollView.contentSize` at runtime? One more thing. Please watch this video all the way through. It helped me TONS with scrollviews: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18

Comment: I had trouble with scrollview and constraints recently, you might want to give a look to my question over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626150/trouble-with-uiscrollview-and-constraints and at the answer I was given. You'll find a sample project where you can start with.

Comment: Andrew Heinlein - Thank you for the quick reply. Funny enough, I used your linked tutorial a year ago to learn how to scroll view with springs and struts. It worked quite well. This time around, I am using auto layout, which I have not mastered and is causing me lots of trouble!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description of how your items are constrained is vague, so I'm going to list all of the constraints you need to make this work.  Then you can compare what you have to what you need and adjust accordingly.

1. Your ScrollView should be pinned on all 4 sides to the MainView.  (This isn't absolutely necessary.  You can constrain your ScrollView however you want, but make sure it can grow as the device and/or orientation changes).
2. Your ContentView should be pinned on all 4 sides to the ScrollView with offsets of 0.
3. Since you want your ScrollView to scroll vertically only, constrain the width of the ContentView to the width of the ScrollView using an *Equal Widths* constraint.  To do this, in the *Document Outline* view, <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from your ContentView to your ScrollView and select *Equal Widths* from the pop up.
4. The height of ContentView will be set by the sum total height of everything in it.  In order for this to work, your topmost button needs to be pinned to the top of the ContentView, all of your buttons and labels should be pinned to their nearest neighbors, and the bottommost label should be pinned to the bottom of the ContentView.  In addition, all of your buttons and labels should have constraints for their widths and heights.  I would suggest setting an explicit width constraint and explicit height constraint for your buttons and centering them horizontally in the ContentView.  For your labels, set an explicit height constraint and pin the left and right edges to the ContentView.

If you have these constraints and no other ones, your ContentView will be properly sized.

Comment: Sorry if my description was vague. I believe I have done all of the above, so let me clarify. I did do research prior to posting and tried a set of similar steps that I found online. I pinned my content view on all four edges to the scroll view and my scroll view to my main view on all four edges. I played with this quite a bit before posting. I constrained my content and main view widths to be the same. I added constraint relationships between all images and labels and their neighbors, plus horizontal centers. Everything looks good when it builds, except it only scrolls a little bit!

Comment: Make sure the `constant` of the constraint to the bottom of the contentView is correct.  If it is a large negative or positive number (depending on the order of the items in the constraint) this could lead to the situation you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new project to test this out and it worked! So I went back to my malfunctioning app, cleared my constraints, and did exactly as described above. That worked too. I believe my mistake was I did not declare a constraint from the last image to the bottom of the view. This time I was more explicit in declaring widths and heights for each image and label. I'm confused because I thought a big auto layout benefit was that I only had to declare relationships and it would adapt sizing. Regardless, this helped so thank you.

Comment: I've been trying to do this for 3 days and still can't work this.  I clearly see the contentView exceeding the scrollview with content, but the scroll stops at the start of the label.  I followed this guide, deleted all the constraints and went one by one, but still the same things happen. 

I also tried some code, but manipulating the scrollView.contentSize on the fly doesn't reflect any changes.  I even print the before and after .contentSize values of the scrollView and see the height going bigger, but still can't scroll all of the content.

please help.

Comment: UPDATE: I set the height constraint of the last label as >= the actual size, and voila! it worked.  I didn't even needed the last label to be attached to the border of the scrollView(don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

Using contentView, like you said, usually fixes the issue. So chances are you need to take a second look at your contraints. Maybe try this solution in a clean/new project to see that it works. (it does work). My guess would be that some of your constraints conflict each other.

Otherwise I think it would be a good idea to `setContentSize` of your scrollView in your `viewDidLoad`.

Another hack would be to place 2 UI objects with their alphas set to zero on the right top corner and left bottom corner. This would hint scrollView to set its contentSize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try it in a new project to see what happens and learn it in a simpler view first. Do you think my navigation controller could be causing me problems?

Comment: Update - I started a new project and used Vacawama's steps. It works. I'd be excited, but I'm no closer to figuring out what mistake is causing my app to not work! At this point my only solution is start over! I'll keep trouble shooting. Thanks for the help!